# Change style of multiple element groups simultaneously on hover using Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, hover

I find myself needing to change style of all elements that have an attribute in common (let's say a class name) when one of these elements is hovered. This is super easy to do with jQuery, like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.bookId4').hover( function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', '#F00');
   },
   function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', '#000');
   });
});
```

Though I don't know how to achieve this with Angular. In this example, the elements that have the class `.bookId4` are generated with Angular AJAX call, so I'd like to use Angular to create the hover effect as well. Thank you!

**EDIT**

To explain further, I will have many divs being generated with an AJAX call, and the div's that are in the same group will have the same class. This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="bookId{{ privateTour.booking.id }}"> <!-- Wrapper for hover effect -->
```

When one of the divs is hovered I want ALL of the divs (not only the div that is being hovered) with the same class (or some other value that they may have in common) to have a hover effect. My preferred way would be for Angular to search the whole page for all divs with a certain class name and apply a style to that class (to not have to for example generate tons of CSS for all the classes that were generated, which I'm not even sure it would work).

Comment: you can use `css` or `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found using an ng-class condition to be the best solution, and a variable decides what group should be highlighted. This line that I initially tried using did not work correctly:

```
<div ng-class="hovering == privateTour.booking.id ? 'hl' : ''" ng-mouseenter="hovering = privateTour.booking.id" ng-mouseleave="hovering = 0"> <!-- Wrapper for hover effect -->
```

For some reason, only the hovered div was highlighted, so I had to send the signal to a variable using a function instead for it to have a global effect. I ended up using this code for the div wrappers:

```
<div ng-class="hovering == privateTour.booking.id ? 'hl' : ''" ng-mouseenter="setHover(privateTour.booking.id)" ng-mouseleave="setHover(0)"> <!-- Wrapper for hover effect -->
```

And I wrote this simple function in the scope:

```
$scope.setHover = function(bookId) {
    $scope.hovering = bookId;
};
```

And here's the style for the highlight class .hl:

```
.hl {
background-color: red;
}
```

Thank you for everyone giving the lead of ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave directives, Here is the simple code, you can build on top of it to meet your requirements

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example73-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="">
<h1 ng-style="myStyle" ng-mouseenter="myStyle={'background-color':'blue'}"" ng-mouseleave="myStyle={'background-color':'none'}"">Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply simple css solution for hover, like

```
.bookId4:hover {
    background-color: '#F00';
}
```

No need for angular or jQuery :-)

Comment: He is looking for a an angular solution, sometimes dynamic elements don't obey predefined CSS rules(loaded during page load), and might need re-render.

Comment: It is the other way round, some javascript solutions do not work with dynamic elements unless reinitialized.

Comment: I would love for this to work, but as Stack Learner says, I need this to be angular, as the classes are loaded dynamically, and I don't know what they will be called. When a div with class .bookId4 is hovered, I want all the divs with class .bookId4 to be highlighted. Same for .bookId48, .bookId113, bookId1029 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I agree with using ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave.
I did a example hope can help you

https://embed.plnkr.co/Cxfv0I9IEfBhZYj8A3zS/

Answer (score 1):

> use ng-class, create one scope variable which is by default false.
>   when mouseEnter OR mouseLeave event occurs make it TRUE/False accordingly.

```
<style>
    .bookId4{color: red;}
</style>        
<span  ng-mouseenter="ctrl.hovered()" ng-mouseout="ctrl.nothovered()"  ng-class="{ 'bookId4' : ctrl.ishovered==true }">soemthing 1</span>
        <span  ng-mouseenter="ctrl.hovered()" ng-mouseout="ctrl.nothovered()" ng-class="{ 'bookId4' : ctrl.ishovered==true }">soemthing 2</span>
        <span  ng-mouseenter="ctrl.hovered()" ng-mouseout="ctrl.nothovered()" ng-class="{ 'bookId4' : ctrl.ishovered==true }">soemthing 3</span>

            _this.ishovered =false;    
            _this.hovered = function(){
                _this.ishovered =true;
            }
            _this.nothovered = function(){
                _this.ishovered =false;
            }
```